# Where is the Raspberry Pi temperature measured?

Tags: raspbian, temperature

Through the command `vcgencmd measure_temp` I can get the Raspberry Pi's temperature in Raspbian, therefore I know that it is possible to measure the temperature. Unfortunately I cannot really find a reliable source where this temperature is actually measured. Is this the CPU Temperature? Is the thermometer directly integrated in the CPU/SoC? Or is there a dedicated component? I already consultet the [SoC's datasheet](https://www.raspberrypi.org/app/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf) but could not find any hint for a thermometer.

Comment: This is not a duplicate because I know that there IS a thermometer. But not WHERE this exact component is located and which temperature is measured.

Comment: agree, no duplicate

Answer (score 3):

It's actually the GPU temperature, so it's inside the Soc. Don't know how accurate it is though

Comment: Thanks! Could you please provide a reliable source? That would be great!

Comment: odd then that pure CPU load causes the temperature to rise. do you have a reference?

Comment: I would guess that the GPU is integrated in the same package with the CPU in the SoC. RAM is also shared between CPU and GPU. So maybe the whole chip temperature is measured.

Comment: https://elinux.org/RPI_vcgencmd_usage and https://github.com/nezticle/RaspberryPi-BuildRoot/wiki/VideoCore-Tools have all the options listed with details about this being VideoCore based

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @rob this [link](http://github.com/nezticle/RaspberryPi-BuildRoot/wiki/VideoCore-Tools) provides the answer:

```
`vcgencmd measure_temp`
Shows core temperature of BCM2835 SoC.
```

In my understanding that means it is neither the CPU nor the GPU temperature but the whole SoC package temperature. Therefore the temperature is influenced by both CPU and GPU activity and measured as a combined value due to heatspreading over the whole chip/package.